# Restart mixed effect model estimation with previously estimated values

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, lmer

I'm using `lmer()` in package `lme4` to estimate mixed effects models.  This works well, but now I want to run the estimation process for a fixed number of iterations, then resume the process by specifying start values, as calculated by the last estimation process.

According to the help for `?lmer` this is possible, by setting the arguments:

- `start` - these are the new start values, and according to the help one can extract the value in slot `ST` from a fitted model and use these, i.e. use `x@ST`
- `maxiter` - supplied as a named argument to `control`

So, for example, suppose I want to fit a `lme` using the `iris` data, one can try this:

```
library(lme4)

# Fit model with limited number of iterations

frm <- "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species"

x <- lmer(frm, data=iris, 
          verbose=TRUE, control=list(maxIter=1), model=FALSE)

# Capture starting values for next set of iterations
start <- list(ST=x@ST)

# Update model
twoStep <-  lmer(frm, data=iris, 
          verbose=TRUE, control=list(maxIter=100), model=TRUE, 
          start=start)
```

This works.  Take a look at the output, where the **first column** is the REML, i.e. the random effect maximum likelihood.  Notice especially that the REML in model 2 starts where model 1 terminates:

```
> x <- lmer(frm, data=iris, 
+           verbose=TRUE, control=list(maxIter=1), model=FALSE)
  0:     264.60572: 0.230940 0.0747853  0.00000
  1:     204.22878: 0.518239  1.01025 0.205835
  1:     204.22878: 0.518239  1.01025 0.205835

> # Capture starting values for next set of iterations
> start <- list(ST=x@ST)

> # Update model
> twoStep <-  lmer(frm, data=iris, 
+           verbose=TRUE, control=list(maxIter=100), model=TRUE, 
+           start=start)
  0:     204.22878: 0.518239  1.01025 0.205835
  1:     201.51667: 0.610272  2.00277 0.286049
  2:     201.46706: 0.849203  1.94906 0.358809
  3:     201.44614: 0.932371  1.88581 0.482423
  4:     201.39421:  1.00909  1.71078 0.871824
  5:     201.36543:  1.00643  1.60453  1.01663
  6:     201.31066:  1.00208  1.35520  1.27524
  7:     201.28458:  1.08227  1.22335  1.35147
  8:     201.24330:  1.50333 0.679759  1.31698
  9:     201.11881:  1.95760 0.329767 0.936047
```

However, when I have a different value of `maxIters` this no longer works:

```
x <- lmer(frm, data=iris, 
          verbose=TRUE, control=list(maxIter=3), model=FALSE)
start <- list(ST=x@ST)
twoStep <-  lmer(frm, data=iris, 
                 verbose=TRUE, control=list(maxIter=100), model=TRUE, 
                 start=start)
```

Notice that **the REML value restarts at 264**, i.e. the beginning:

```
> x <- lmer(frm, data=iris, 
+           verbose=TRUE, control=list(maxIter=3), model=FALSE)
  0:     264.60572: 0.230940 0.0747853  0.00000
  1:     204.22878: 0.518238  1.01025 0.205835
  2:     201.94075:  0.00000  1.51757 -1.18259
  3:     201.71473:  0.00000  1.69036 -1.89803
  3:     201.71473:  0.00000  1.69036 -1.89803

> # Capture starting values for next set of iterations
> start <- list(ST=x@ST)

> # Update model
> twoStep <-  lmer(frm, data=iris, 
+           verbose=TRUE, control=list(maxIter=100), model=TRUE, 
+           start=start)
  0:     264.60572: 0.230940 0.0747853  0.00000
  1:     204.22878: 0.518238  1.01025 0.205835
  2:     201.94075:  0.00000  1.51757 -1.18259
  3:     201.71473:  0.00000  1.69036 -1.89803
  4:     201.64641:  0.00000  1.82159 -2.44144
  5:     201.63698:  0.00000  1.88282 -2.69497
  6:     201.63649:  0.00000  1.89924 -2.76298
  7:     201.63649: 4.22291e-08  1.90086 -2.76969
  8:     201.63649: 4.22291e-08  1.90086 -2.76969
```

---

**Question: How can I reliably restart `lmer()` with start values obtained from a previously fitted model?**

---

Session information:

```
packageVersion("lme4")
[1] ‘0.999999.2’
```

Comment: This is very likely a bug; the `start` functionality of `lme4` has not been very thoroughly exercised, so I'm sure there are lots of issues like this.  How strong is your need to use the stable rather than the development version?  I will look into this, but we're hoping to do most of our debugging on the stable version ...

Comment: @BenBolker I can use either dev or test code, since I'm just running some experiments at the moment.  I can help, if you let me know where to find the dev branch.

Comment: it's on github: `library(devtools); install_github("lme4",user="lme4")`. It is easier in this version to extract the deviance function and use it in your own optimization, which you might prefer if you want more control.  Alternatively, do try out the `start` experiment and let me know at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues if you find something not working ...

Comment: @BenBolker I've installed the dev version, but no luck yet with restarting - I just don't seem to be able to construct the appropriate value for `theta` from the model object.  I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: I've logged an issue at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/55

Comment: This should be fixed now for `lmer` (although not for `glmer`, which is slightly trickier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a confirmed bug in lme4 and as per the comments

> I've logged an issue at github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/55 –  Andrie Jul 2 '13 at 15:42
>
> This should be fixed now for lmer (although not for glmer, which is slightly trickier). –  Ben Bolker Jul 14

That was back when the version  was < 0.99999911-6; [lme4 on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) has had versions > 1.0-4 since 21-Sep-2013.